# Do I need to place anything under the rubber mats to protect the tile from discoloration?

Tags: flooring, tile, floor, subfloor

I'm setting up a small home gym and wanted to place some rubber mats (rolled or interlocking) on the tile. Do I need to place anything under the mats to protect the tile and grout from discoloration? I'm not worried about the tile cracking, just discoloration.

Comment: "Do I need to place anything under the rubber mats to protect the tile from discoloration?" is the only objective question we can answer. The rest are very subjective and open to opinion which is explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Please [edit] to get rid of the opinion based questions. Also, take the [tour] - it will help. ;)

Comment: I have used the thicker interlocking mats on a cement floor and it was definitely discolored after a few years.

Comment: @FreeMan edited! question is purely about tile discoloration protection now

Comment: @MarcBernier did you ever add anything under to help with discoloration? This room might not be a gym forever for me

Comment: Well done! So many people ignore those types of requests. Thanks for playing by the rules here! What kind of tiles are these? Are they porcelain coated tile? Stone tile? Something else? Glazed tiles have a fairly non-porous surface and may not pick up any staining while the grout may get stained as @MarcBernier's concrete did. Natural stone or other non-glazed tile may act more like concrete in this respect.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm not 100% sure, but they are either ceramic or porcelain. I think because of the grout, my best bet might be to put something under the mats to try and prevent staining. Maybe some non slip rug pads or paper?

Comment: A picture of the tile may help. I would think that something between the mats and the tile wouldn't hurt, but it's got to be something that the mats won't slip on, unless you're doing wall-to-wall.